# Search bar built using React that queries Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-router

Relatively new to React and attempting to incorporate a search bar that queries a 'businesses' node in my Firebase database. Could use some guidance/input on the flow of my components.

My initial instinct told me it should go something like 'router > SearchBarLogic > SearchBar > BusinessIndexLogic > BusinessIndex' with a term being passed down from my SearchBar to my BusinessIndexLogic for aid in generating my query.

Going to paste the relevant code from the components I mentioned above below. Any insight would be much appreciated.

router.js

```
const router = (
  <Router history={browserHistory} >
    <Route path='/' component={App} >
       <IndexRoute component={HomeLogic} />
       <Route path='businesses' >
         <IndexRoute component={SearchBarLogic} />
         <Route path='addbusiness' component={AddBusinessFormLogic} />
         <Route path=':id' >
           <IndexRoute component={BusinessesProfileLogic} />
           <Route path='deletebusiness' component={DeleteBusinessPageLogic} />
         </Route>
       </Route>   
   </Router>
);
```

SearchBarLogic.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import SearchBar from '../layouts/SearchBar';

class SearchBarLogic extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      term: "",
    };
  }

  search(term) {
    this.setState({ term });
  }

  render(){
    let term = this.state.term

    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar
          term={term}
          onSearchTermChange={(term) => {this.search(term)}}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default SearchBarLogic;
```

SearchBar.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import BusinessIndexLogic from '../logic/businesses/BusinessIndexLogic';

class SearchBar extends Component {
  render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="nav-wrapper">
        <form>
          <div className="input-field">
            <input
              id="search"
              type="search"
              value={this.props.term}
              onChange={(event) => {this.props.onSearchTermChange(event.target.value)}}
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div>
        <BusinessIndexLogic
          value={this.props.term}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
  }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

BusinessIndexLogic.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BusinessStorage } from '../../../config/FirebaseConstants';
import BusinessIndex from '../../pages/businesses/BusinessIndex';

class BusinessIndexLogic extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      allBusinesses: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let _this = this;
    let businesses = {};

    if (this.props.value === ""){
      BusinessStorage.ref('users/').once('value', function(allData) {
        allData.forEach(function(data) {
          data.forEach(function(userNode) {
            if (userNode.val().type === 'businesses') {
              if (userNode.val().deletedAt !== true) {
                let companyName = userNode.val().companyName;
                let idNumber = data.key;
                businesses[companyName] = {name: companyName, id: idNumber}
              }
            }
          })
        })
      }).then(function(user) {
        let keys = Object.keys(businesses).sort();
        let sortedHash = {};
        let sortedArray = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
          let key = keys[i];
          sortedArray.push(sortedHash[key] = businesses[key]);
        }

        _this.setState({allBusinesses: sortedArray}, function afterBusinessSet() {

        });
      })
  } else {
    BusinessStorage.ref('users/').startAt(`${this.props.value}`).once('value', function(allData) {
      allData.forEach(function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(userNode) {
          if (userNode.val().type === 'business') {
            if (userNode.val().deletedAt !== true) {
              let companyName = userNode.val().companyName;
              let idNumber = data.key;
              businesses[companyName] = {name: companyName, id: idNumber}
            }
          }
        })
      })
    }).then(function(user) {
      let keys = Object.keys(businesses).sort();
      let sortedHash = {};
      let sortedArray = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        let key = keys[i];
        sortedArray.push(sortedHash[key] = businesses[key]);
  }

      _this.setState({allBusinesses: sortedArray}, function afterBusinessSet() {

      });
    })
  }
  }

  render() {
    let allBusinesses = this.state.allBusinesses;
    let pathName = this.props.location.pathname;

    return (
      <BusinessIndex
        allBusinesses={allBusinesses}
        pathName={pathName}
      />
    )
  }
}

export default BusinessIndexLogic;
```

And the error I'm currently getting in my console is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null` which isn't helping much. Like I said, any insight or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6895#issuecomment-281405036), that error means that your code is throwing a different error that's preventing your components from rendering. Is there an error above that one in the console? If not, add some error handling with console.logs. It's probably something in your Promise chain (Firebase call); add .catch(err => console.log(err)) to the end of the chain, but in general do some error handling throughout.

Comment: Ah yes, there was a different error appearing above that, related to the pathName prop in the IndexLogic component. Restructured my router when factoring in my search bar and that threw that off. Also moved my Firebase query logic from componentDidMount to a componentDidUpdate method. Seems to be passing the term effectively and I've been able to target the source of my issue to the .startAt query. That needs to be called in a different location. Thanks for the suggestion! Wouldn't have spotted that other error without it.